# Issue pulling data from form inputs using Meteor framework

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I tried to create an input form which would take your full name that you entered and display it for you. My forum takes the entry but it won't display it at all. 
This is my code:

```
<head>
  <title>InputForum</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> Forum}}
</body>

<template name ="Forum">
<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Donald"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>Click "Try it" to display the value of each element in the form.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
</template>
```

And this is my JS code

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.Forum.helpers({
    myFunction: function () {
      alert();
      var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
      var text = "";
      var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
          text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
  }
});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

I'm pretty new and i'm sure soon i'll be able to figure these things out my self, but I could use a little help right now.
Any answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The actual code looks fine and works in isolation (see below).

With this in mind it seems there is some problem with your meteor framework defining the function. Check that the function is defined and that it is actually being called (use an `alert()` in the function and see if it appears on click.)

```js
var myFunction = function () {
      var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
      var text = "";
      var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
          text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Donald"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>Click "Try it" to display the value of each element in the form.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Like this?   if (Meteor.isClient) {
 
  Template.Forum.helpers({
 myFunction: function () {
   alert();
      var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
      var text = "";
      var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
          text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
  }
});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}

Comment: am i just supposed to put alert(); in the function like that

Comment: Yes, you need to debug your script. Add `alert('testing')` and click the button to see if it pops up. If not, there is a broader issue with your framework.

Comment: Nothing popped up. So that means it's a framework issue

Comment: how would I go about doing that?